# Character automatically duplicated when using US International Keyboard in Windows 10

Tags: keyboard

When I press one time in the US International Keyboard the following symbols [~] [^] ['] ["]
they automatically appear as [~~] [^^] [''] [""],
and I have to press [backspace] to delete one of them.

Also, I cannot use the combination ["a] to create ä and so on due to the above problem. I have to resort to using RAlt for this.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you remote into a computer? Sounds like on one place you have it set as US Int, and on another you have it set as US.

Comment: I don't even know how to set up remote use actually.